# Website works fine in firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My website has a table that is supposed to be displayed beside a image, it works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome!
CSS Below:

```
#right{ float:right; position: absolute; }
#left{ float:left; position: absolute; }
```

and image and table:

```
<div class="left">
      <div><img style="width: 599px; height: 343px;" alt="" src="images/picture.png">
        <div class="right">
          <div style="
    margin-left: 20px; width: 638px;    height: 343px;  overflow: scroll;">
```

Comment: You didn't close any of your div tags? I'm not positive I understand based on your code what you're trying to do. But if you are trying to float one right and the other left, you should close your tags around your desired content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you noticed this, but you did not close your DIV tags. This is probably why it won't work in Chrome. Firefox probably autocompletes the tags but chrome might take the tags literally and see that you didn't put an end tag. Try putting the end tags there and see if it works then.

Comment: Thanks, Finally I Fixed it! I never knew chrome cared that much! But Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it won't work in any browser unless, it cached the style for .left and .right

```
   .right{ float:right; }
   .left{ float:left; }

<div style="position:relative">
    <div class="left">
          <div><img style="width: 599px; height: 343px;" alt="" src="images/picture.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
          <div style="
        margin-left: 20px; width: 638px;    height: 343px;  overflow: scroll;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You are using Id selector, you have to use class selector

Comment: i changed # to . but now the table goes under the image.

Comment: are you trying to display the img on right and other div on right? then you need to update a htm l and css.. give me a min